# CMakeLists folder is not getting ignored with .gitignore

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, gitignore

My code structure is as follows

```
cpppen
|
|-c++11-features
|  |
|  |-async_task
      | 
      | - async_task.cpp
      | - CMakeFiles/ 
      | - CMakeLists.txt
```

I want to add the `CMakeFiles/` folder to `.gitignore`

For some reason it doesn't seem to work.

```
*.o
*.cbp
*.cmake
CMakeCache.txt
cmake_install.cmake
bin/
build/
CMakeLists.txt.user
**/CMakeFiles/
venv
**/.idea
CMakeScripts
Testing
Makefile

install_manifest.txt
compile_commands.json
CTestTestfile.cmake

cmake-build-debug/

c++11-features/async_task/async_task.exe
```

Can someone point out why it is not ignoring the `CMakeFiles` folder under `async_task`. What mistake am I making in my `.gitignore`

Comment: Keep in mind that `.gitignore` doesn't apply if you've already added the file to the index (or to a commit)

Comment: @o11c - how do I fix that? remove the file from git ?

Comment: `git rm --cached`

Comment: @o11c - doesn't help. I have tried that.

Answer (score 1):

If the folder `cpppen` is the root folder of Git (with the folder `.git`), it should work the way you wrote (`**/CMakeFiles/`) it in `.gitignore`. But `.gitignore` must also be created there (can of course be in any subdirectory, but normally/be default `.gitignore` is in the root folder of git).

```
cpppen
.gitignore
...
```

If you have tracked the folder `CMakeFiles` in any previous commit, you must first *untrack* this folder from Git. Do this with following command:

```
# Execute from Git root folder
git rm -r --cached c++11/async_task/CMakeLists
```

After that, you can add (`git add .`) your changes and commit (`git commit -m "No longer tracking CMakeLists to include in gitignore"`) them. Now you are ready to push (`git push`) and after this, you can go to your remote repository, and the folder `CMakeLists` will no longer be visible there!

---

There is also another way (*more professional*/*clearer*), how you can add the folder `CMakeLists` to your `.gitignore`.

As it is now noted (`**/CMakeFiles/`) **all** folders in the repository that have this folder name (*CMakeFiles*) are ignored. What if you suddenly create another folder with the same name, but want it to be available on the remote repository? Therefore I would make the entry in `.gitignore` as follows:

```
c++11/async_task/CMakeLists/
```

This is how you define that only the folder you want (`CMakeFiles` in `c++11/async_task`) is ignored and not any other folders with the same name. Is a *small thing* that can make a **big difference** ;-)